# Footer appears mid-screen

Tags: css, html

I know there are duplicates of similar questions to this but I just can't get my footer to stay at the bottom, and I've tried multiple suggested fixes. Please show me how to move the footer to the bottom of the page. Does it have something to do with the body? Whoever posts a solution could you say what it was that was incorrect?

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CopperMug</title>
<link href="Coppermug Stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

   <div class="navbar" id="navbarSupportedContent">
<ul class="navbar-nav">
<li class="nav-item active">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
</li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
          </li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
</li>
   </div>
<body id="body">
       <div>
           <img src="../Final Logo Assets/Coppermug banner no background 2-min.png" class="img" id="logo"> 
       </div>
</body>
    <footer>
        <a class="service-link" href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
        <a class="service-link" href="#">Terms of Service</a>
          </footer>
</html>

    @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html {
    background-image: url("../Final Logo Assets/Blur Mug-min Opacity-min.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}   
#body {

}
#header, 
li .nav-link {
    font-family: "Copperplate Gothic";
    color: #000000
}
#logo {  display: block;
  margin-left: 26%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 12%;
  width: 50%;}

#navbarSupportedContent {
    color: black;
    font-family: "Copperplate Gothic";
    font-size: .99em;
    padding: 1em;
}

#navbarSupportedContent li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
div #navbarSupportedContent {
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 150%;
    margin-left: 3%;
}
.navbar-nav {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 150%;
}

footer .service-link {
    color: #000000;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
        clear: both;
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: -40px;
}
```

Comment: [IMG]http://i65.tinypic.com/6pnwvn.jpg[/IMG]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have currently is a footer element which exists as just another plain element in the page flow (FYI, you have a redundant `position:relative` on it), so where it ends up is wherever the content above it ends (ie your image).

If you want a footer slammed to the bottom of the viewport that always remains visible regardless of content length or scroll position, then you'd use `position: fixed` on your footer, as crodev's answer shows. However this takes up screen real estate and is used with intention and good reason (like some action bar during some kind of funneled user experience).

However, for regular page circumstances, when you have short content, and want the footer to appear at the bottom of the viewport, it's best using a flex layout like below (which offers all kinds of advantages as well):

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/vPBGEP)

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}

#header {
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 100px;
}

#content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
  
  /* to test a longer page */
  /* min-height: 3000px; */
}

#footer {
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.section {
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header" class="section">
    header
  </div>
  
  <div id="content" class="section">
    content
  </div>
  
  <div id="footer" class="section">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="footer">
   <p>Footer</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```